# Jq select condition

Tags: json, select, command-line-arguments, jq

I have a log file and want to grep data from it, so I use Jq to filter some data by parameters.

As I said above, I will filter data based on the argument passed to Jq

For details:

The structure of my log file:

```
 {
    city: "",
    phone_number: "",
    address: "",
    zip_code: "",
    person : {
        name: "",
        sex: "",
        ...
    }
 }
```

My expected is I want to ignore attributes use to filter if that is `empty` or `null`.

For example:

```
cat my_log_file.log | jq -r --arg city ${city} --arg name ${name}  'select(.city == $city and .person.name == $name)'
```

With the command above if `${city}` argument I passed is `empty` or `null` then I want to remove the filter with **city** and just filter with **name**

I have tried but still doesn't work

Comment: `empty` is not a JSON value.  Do you mean the empty string `""`, or the empty object `{}`, or both?  It would be helpful if you followed the [mcve] guidelines!

Comment: @peak empty is `""`. Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether a value, say $value, is `null` or `""`, one could write:

```
$value == null or $value == ""
```

So you could achieve what you want by using this jq program:

```
def agrees(value): 
  value == null or value == "" or . == value;

select( (.city | agrees($city)) and
        (.person.name | agrees($name)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... I want to ignore attributes if that is empty or null

To remove unwanted keys from an object, you could  pass it to a filter such as:

```
with_entries(select(.value | (. != "" and . != {} and . != null)))
```

Comment: In my case, I want to ignore attributes use to filter if the arguments passed to them is `empty`. Sorry about my question is confusing for you